# How to prevent ContextMenu from closing?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I want to add TextField as a Component to MenuItem. It works, but as soon as I click on the field, ContextMenu receives DetachEvent and closes. Is there a way to prevent ContextMenu from detaching when I click on the one of MenuItem's?

```java
Button btnFilter = createFilterButton();
ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
cm.setOpenOnClick(true);
cm.setTarget(btnFilter);
TextField tf = new TextField();
MenuItem mi = cm.addItem(tf, e->{});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by calling method *add()* instead of *addItem()*

```java
Button btnFilter = createFilterButton();
ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
cm.setOpenOnClick(true);
cm.setTarget(btnFilter);
TextField tf = new TextField();
tf.addValueChangeListener(e -> {...});
cm.add(tf);
```